# Why this styling of Spec 2 app does not work?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am trying to add style to `SpTextPresenter` (**Pharo 9, Spec 2, Windows 10**). I have `MyApp` class:

```
SpApplication subclass: #MyApp
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    package: 'MyAdm'
```

with class method `uniqueInstance` (and class instance - "singleton" idea was copy-pasted from LibC):

```
uniqueInstance
    ^ uniqueInstance ifNil: [ uniqueInstance := self new ]
```

and an instance method `initialize`:

```
initialize
    super initialize.
    self useBackend: #Morphic with: MyAppConfiguration new.
```

and `MyAppConfiguration` class:

```
SpMorphicConfiguration subclass: #MyAppConfiguration
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    package: 'MyAdm'
```

with the method `configure`:

```
configure: anApplication
    super configure: anApplication.
    self styleSheet addClass: 'text' with: [ :style |
        style addPropertyFontWith: [ :font |
            font bold: true;
                  size: 20;
                  name: 'Courier'
        ].
    ].
```

Somewhere in the code I do:

```
.....
    "presenterClass is an argument which is a class of my presenter"
    presenter := MyApp uniqueInstance newPresenter: presenterClass.
    presenter openWithSpec.
    presenter updatePresenter.
....
```

I have several presenters, but one of them really contains `text` variable which is created in a `initializePresenters` method:

```
initializePresenters
    text := self newText addStyle: 'text'.
    super initializePresenters
```

But the result is bad - the `text` has standard view, with a standard font, nothing changed! Where is the bug? I want to see in the `text` (of `SpTextPresenter` type) my custom font.

**EDIT:** btw, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65563655/how-to-change-the-font-in-the-sptextpresenter) does not work too.

Comment: It seems the problem was in the `uniqueInstance` - it is a class instance variable which was created from a version without completed styling functionality. After removing of it, I got a worked version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you declare a singleton and you save the image, it will stay alive between sessions. *As anything in Pharo, because is a live environment*.
Now, that question makes me think you are lacking the basics of Pharo. And as I said here before (in other question), learning *by stackoverflow* is not the best way to learn Pharo.
Take a look at this site: https://pharo.org/documentation, there are a lot of resources for learning there.
Also, there a discord server where you can ask anything and there will be a lot of people willing to help you (me included) there: https://discord.gg/QewZMZa

Answer (score 0):

The next is my understanding of the fault reason from newbie point of view.

1. I wrote a singleton (`uniqueInstance`)
2. Then I added other parts of the code which implements the styling functionality
3. It did not work
4. And my understanding is that the `uniqueInstance` was not re-created each time when I run my application. I added `uniqueInstance := nil` and I found that styling began to work. Maybe `uniqueInstance` was saved in the image (?) and when I added required parts of the code, the application continued to use the old `uniqueInstance` from the image? I am not sure... But assign it to `nil` fixed the problem.
5. So, I decided to avoid this singleton approach and to create application instance explicitly.
6. To be honest the code from the question did not help - but [THIS VERSION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65563655/how-to-change-the-font-in-the-sptextpresenter) works fine.